# MVC logging scope

Tags: logging, scope, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I read that inside MVC middleware framework use logging scope withing contoller's action:

> Use Scopes sparingly, and only for actions with a bounded start and end. For example, the framework provides **a scope around MVC actions**. Avoid nesting many scopes within one another.

And

> A scope is an IDisposable type returned by calling the ILogger.BeginScope method, which lasts from the moment it is created until it is disposed. Any logging state, such as a transaction id, is attached to the scope when it is created.

I'm trying to use this feature to write some log information. I executed steps below:

1) create Asp.net core MVC app 
2) set property "IncludeScopes" as "true" in appsetting.json
3) create controller and action like this:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<TodoController> _logger;
    public TodoController(ILogger<TodoController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(1000, "Listing all items started");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        _logger.LogInformation(1000, "Listing all items finished");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I expect that my log messages flow always will contains only "Listing all items started" and "Listing all items finished" parts which not separated by each other. 
But when I started two requests in the same time a got log flow as:


    RequestId: xxx Listing all items started
    RequestId: yyy Listing all items started
    RequestId: xxx Listing all items finished
    RequestId: yyy Listing all items finished

What's the reason? Is it correct behaviour and I misunderstood "scope" term in context of logging?

Comment: Don't put tags into the question title, unless it's a organic to the conversation! http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logging scopes help to create scopes by which any log statements created *within* it would have that information available.

Following out is from `ConsoleLogger` with `IncludeScopes` set to `true`:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      => RequestId:0HKT6JC0EVFNA RequestPath:/api/values
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/values
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      => RequestId:0HKT6JC0EVFNA RequestPath:/api/values => WebApplication8.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication8)
      Executing action method WebApplication8.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication8) with arguments () - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      => RequestId:0HKT6JC0EVFNA RequestPath:/api/values => WebApplication8.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication8)
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      => RequestId:0HKT6JC0EVFNA RequestPath:/api/values => WebApplication8.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication8)
      Executed action WebApplication8.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication8) in 322.8533ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      => RequestId:0HKT6JC0EVFNA RequestPath:/api/values
      Request finished in 428.477ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

If you notice the above log, here `RequestId:0HKT6JC0EVFNA` is being printed for every log statement (as mentioned earlier all log statements within a scope or nested scope would get information from all those scopes)

Some log scopes that are created by default in ASP.NET are the `RequestId` scope as seen above and also scope around MVC's controller action invocation as seen from the log(example this line: `=> WebApplication8.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApplication8)`)

You can yourself creates scopes too if you need:

```
using (logger.BeginScope("OrderOrchestrationId:{OrderOrchestrationId}", orderOrchestrationId))
{
   // any log statements from here on would have `OrderOrchestrationId` available
}
```

**Note:**
All loggers do not support scopes by default. In case of `ConsoleLogger` it prints out scopes in text format but scopes really shine in case of structured logging as discussed next.

**How are scopes useful?**
ASP.NET logging framework allows you to do `structured logging`. For example, in the above code `{OrderOrchestrationId}` was used for this purpose. [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) has a logger for ASP.NET 5 which implements structured logging and using this you can for example write data as `json` data to Azure's DocumentDB.
So in this case if `OrderOrchestrationId` was written to Azure's DocumentDB, you can search the logs with this id which would have been difficult to do with flat text file searching.